# How to typeset appropriate "does not entail" symbol?

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a LaTeX symbol that means *"A does not entail B"*. The mathematical symbol I found for this is `⊬`, however I haven't found any way of displaying it properly.

How can I convey the desired meaning?

Comment: This is “does not entail”, which is different from “does not imply”.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for pointing that out, I will change the question!

Comment: We're getting a lot of clever ways to fake a symbol that’s in `amssymb`.

Comment: Although the accepted answer has been edited to list the others now.

Comment: Note that for logic, you need to negate the symbol from the `turnstile` package: none of the font packages which provide these symbols in maths will do the job because these aren't encoded, sadly, as extensible symbols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\doesnotentail{\mkern-2mu\not\mkern2mu\vdash}
\begin{document}
$A\doesnotentail B$

$A\vdash B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

And some other ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,stackengine}
\newcommand\doesnotentail{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{.175em}{\vdash}{\scriptstyle/}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
$A\doesnotentail B$ via stackengine

$A\vdash B$ \textbackslash vdash

$A\nvdash B$ \textbackslash nvdash
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The `mathabx`  fonts define a plethora of such symbols. Here is a code to use them without loading the whole font:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%[14pt]
 \usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{%
 <-6> matha5
<6-7> matha6
<7-8> matha7
<8-9> matha8
<9-10> matha9
 <10-12> matha10
  <12-> matha12
  } {}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{% 
<-6> matha5 
<6-7> matha6 
<7-8> mathb7 
<8-9> mathb8 
<9-10> mathb9 
<10-12> mathb10 
<12-> mathb12 
}{}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}%

\DeclareMathSymbol{\nvdash}{\mathrel}{matha}{"26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ndashv}{\mathrel}{matha}{"27}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nvDash}{\mathrel}{matha}{"2E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nDashv}{\mathrel}{matha}{"2F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nVdash}{\mathrel}{matha}{"2A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ndashV}{\mathrel}{matha}{"2B}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\nVDash}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"2A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nDashV}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"2B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nVvdash}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"2E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ndashVv}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"2F}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{4}
\texttt{\textbackslash nvdash} &\quad & \nvdash &\hspace{4em} & \texttt{\textbackslash ndashv} &\quad & \ndashv \\
\texttt{\textbackslash nvDash} &\quad & \nvDash &\hspace{4em} & \texttt{\textbackslash nDashv} &\quad & \nDashv \\
\texttt{\textbackslash nVdash} &\quad & \nvDash &\hspace{4em} & \texttt{\textbackslash ndashV} &\quad & \nDashv \\\\
\texttt{\textbackslash nVDash} &\quad & \nVDash &\hspace{4em} & \texttt{\textbackslash nDashV} &\quad & \nDashV \\
\texttt{\textbackslash nVvdash} &\quad & \nVDash &\hspace{4em} & \texttt{\textbackslash nDashV} &\quad & \ndashVv
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good observation! These are additionally in several other packages, including `unicode-math`, `stix` and `stix2`.

Comment: Also in `mnsymbol` and `mdsymbol`.  `mathabx` has the advantage to fit well the default math fonts.

Comment: And several others I know of: anyone who wants the full set can check out the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List.

Comment: For what it's worth, my personal recommendation is to use `unicode math` whenever possible. Latin Modern Math/`lmodern`, Asana Math/newpx, XITS Math/`stix`,Stix Two Math/`stix2`, and TeX Gyre Termes Math/`newtx` are all fonts that have close analogues to legacy packages.

Answer (score 7):

The ⊬ is U+22AC (Does Not Prove).  This is `\nvdash` in `amssymb` and many other packages, including `unicode-math`, `pxfonts`, `MnSymbol`, `fdsymbol`, `mathabx`, `stix` and more.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Or your font package of choice.

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{22AC}{\ensuremath{\nvdash}}

\begin{document}
\( p ⊬ q \) and \(q \nvdash p\).
\end{document}
```

[image: p ⊬ q and q ⊬ p]

The [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) shows what the symbol looks like in many of these fonts.

Even simpler:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% You can \setmainfont and \setmathfont here.

\begin{document}
\( p ⊬ q \) and \(q \nvdash p\).
\end{document}
```

The [List of Symbols Defined by `unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) shows what this symbol looks like in several OpenType fonts (on page 58).

But, the other answers give some really clever ways to fake it, if you want to make things more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution for keeping the negation slash to the height of the “entailment” symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\notvdash}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\vdashnot\vdash}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vdashnot}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \sbox2{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1/$}}%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\mkern2mu$\resizebox{1.1\width}{\ht0}{\box2}\hidewidth\cr
    \box0\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\notvdash B$

\end{document}
```

[image]